# CSS Image positioning messing up

Tags: html, css

So I'm doing a course where I have to use the z-index to tuck an image behind the div below:
Here's what it is supposed to look like: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP9v4.png)
And here is what Mine looks like, even after copying the exact same code, with some tweaks too after reading how other people in my similar situation managed to solve it [My version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvHL5.png).

Here is the code for the stuff I had to change for it to look like the example:

```css
#features{
    padding: 7% 15%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative; 
}
```

```css
.iphone-img{
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Every time I tried to slightly tweak the up and bottom values, the image's positioning would change drastically. I managed to get the exact positioning I wanted when adjusting with google inspect element, but when actually adjusting in vsc I did not manage to get the same result

Comment: Use it as background image and adjust or position your iphone-img with properties like top, right etc.

Comment: Will this affect how responsive the website is in terms of how it will look in a mobile or tablet format?

Comment: Yes, you can use media queries to fix this also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `z-index` in your code.

You need to add it, such as:

```
.element-background {
    position: relative;
}
.element-phone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

This code will position your phone image on top of the background, at the bottom and almost in the center.

Comment: I added the z-index into the code, but when I try to slightly adjust the `bottom` positioning of the image, it goes up to the top of the div so I cant adjust it exactly to where I want it. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you use units? For example `bottom: 10px`? It should definitely work.

Comment: I did try that, but instead of it going upwards by like 10px it goes up by 100px

Comment: It must be something else, as `10px` should be ten pixels, not more. Try to inspect your elements using your browser's developer tools and see the actual value, and if it's indeed 10 or 100 pixels.